# Correct way to connect tables together in Laravel and retrieve in blade

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm currently working on a project in Laravel.

I have 3 TABLES in MySQL.

Clicks - Costs - Profit

I want to show the data from these 3 tables in one blade.

What's the efficient way to achieve this?

For example: Having a shared same column value in each 3 tables, then returning the query with that value from every table.

Or maybe something like a belongsToMany Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is all you want - [link](https://www.webslesson.info/2021/04/laravel-8-tutorial-join-multiple-table-using-eloquent-model.html)

Comment: @Druv, thanks for the answer. Do you think this is efficient enough and it's up to date?

Comment: yeah this post is created in 2021 & up to date & if you just want to show data in a view blade this is enough

Answer (score 0):

What is the database look like, do they share a foreign key? What data you explicitly want to extract and show to the blade?

Comment: There is no foreign key.  

The database kinda looks like this: https://prnt.sc/1vl7m7l